# Analyzing Sonoma County's topography/slope in 2017 fires

Tags: vector, slope, topography

I am looking to create a map of sonoma county's topography. I am looking at one of the components of a fire: slope.

I want to first isolate sonoma county, which is easy enough to do, after that though, I am wondering how to work with topographic data/map (which is usually raster data), and convert it into vector data. Will I be working with a TIN when I do that?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the data. For example, you could categorize the slope raster, then polygonize it. The data format of the polygon layer can be any vector format (shapefile, geopackage, geojson, etc.). (You have a slope raster, right? If you have an *elevation* raster, you'll need to convert it into a slope raster. There are lots of tutorials for that.) But if your goal is simply to present a map of slopes, there's no need to convert to vectors.

Comment: I understand. Got it, thank you.